# How are ARINC 429 BCD dd:mm:yy labels encoded?

Tags: arinc-429

Label 260 (Date) has a dd:mm:yr format, which requires 6 characters. How is this label typically coded? Here is my best guess based on the range of each digit:

| Bit # | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1-8 | Label (260) |
| 9 | SDI |
| 10 | SDI |
| 11 | digit #6 LSB |
| 12 | 0/1 |
| 13 | 0/1 |
| 14 | digit #6 MSB |
| 15 | digit #5 LSB |
| 16 | 0/1 |
| 17 | 0/1 |
| 18 | digit #5 MSB |
| 19 | digit #4 LSB |
| 20 | 0/1 |
| 21 | 0/1 |
| 22 | digit #4 MSB |
| 23 | digit #3 |
| 24 | digit #2 LSB |
| 25 | 0/1 |
| 26 | 0/1 |
| 27 | digit #2 MSB |
| 28 | digit #1 LSB |
| 29 | digit #1 MSB |
| 30 | SSM |
| 31 | SSM |
| 32 | Parity |

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

There is a direct example for label 260 in Table 6-18 of ARINC 429 Part 1 dated May 17th, 2004 that identifies the following bit ranges for the corresponding digit:

```
Bits 29:28 - Day x10
Bits 27:24 - Day x1
Bit  23    - Month x10
Bits 22:19 - Month x1
Bits 18:15 - Year x10
Bits 14:11 - Year x1
```